# Get the ID of a custom Control

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

I have a fairly complex Custom Control that may be used multiple times on any given XPage. In the control I create a couple of viewScope variables that have to be unique to the specific custom Control. I would like to do something like viewScope.put(customControlID + "variableName","Stuff)
But I don't know how to get the custom controls ID

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the current custom control ID with `this.getId()` at the `<xp:view>` level.

If you put this ID into a compositeData variable (e.g. `compositeData.id`) then you can use the ID inside the custom control everywhere you want.

```xml
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    beforePageLoad="#{javascript:compositeData.id = this.getId()}" >
```

Usage in SSJS:

```js
viewScope.put(compositeData.id + "variableName","Stuff")
```

Typically, IDs are named like "_id2", "_id8", ...

Comment: That's a rather clever approach, Knut.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *dataContext* variable:

```
<xp:this.dataContexts>
   <xp:dataContext
      value="#{javascript:this.getId()}"
      var="id">
   </xp:dataContext>
</xp:this.dataContexts>
```

The variable is then accessible as *id* in SSJS...

```
<xp:label id="label1" value="#{javascript:id}" />
```

... or in EL:

```
<xp:label id="label1" value="#{id}" />
```

Comment: That is a very handy solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution as an SSJS function:

```
function getCCId( cmp:javax.faces.component.UIComponent):string{

    try{
        if( typeof( cmp ) === 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite' ){
            return cmp.getId();
        }
        return getCCId( cmp.getParent() )
    }catch(e){}

}
```

The function climbs the component tree until it finds the parent CC and then returns the id.

You can use it f.e. in a label like this:

```
<xp:label id="label1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getCCId( this )}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:label>
```