# Calculating and storing data on page level for use in custom-controls

Tags: xpages

I have to do some calculations which many of my controls needed, and i just want to do it once on every request and store it. (e.g. beforeRenderResponse)

I can not figure out a clean way to achieve this in a custom-control.

I do not want to use the dataContext, because i read some creepy article regarding its performance (Multiple calculations on a singe JSF-cycle).
See: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1112

So i went to objectData, just to figure out, that it has the same problem than the compositeData - It is not available in any custom-control events but beforePageLoad and afterPageLoad.
See: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1099

**Current solutions**

I got two (unsatisfying) solutions for that problem.

I marked the solutions with <!-- Solutions --> in the markup below.

Solution #1:
 Abuses the property "value" of a xp:text to update the objectData.

Solution #2:
 Requires to call the update() method manually.

**Test-setup**

XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xc:dataControl />
</xp:view>
```

Custom-Control (dataControl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    beforePageLoad="#{javascript:object1.sayHello('beforePageLoad')}" 
    afterPageLoad="#{javascript:object1.sayHello('afterPageLoad')}"
    afterRestoreView="#{javascript:object1.sayHello('afterRestoreView')}" 
    beforeRenderResponse="#{javascript:object1.sayHello('beforeRenderResponse')}"
    afterRenderResponse="#{javascript:object1.sayHello('afterRenderResponse')}">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xe:objectData var="object1">
            <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript://
                print("object1 is created");
                return new ds.DataTest();   }]]>
            </xe:this.createObject>
        </xe:objectData>
    </xp:this.data>

    <!-- Solutions -->

    <!-- Solution #1 -->    
    <xp:text id="computedField1" value="#{javascript: object1.update(); return ''; }" />

    <!-- Solution #2  -->
    <xp:button value="dataObject update" id="updateButton">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:object1.update()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <!-- /Solutions -->

    <div>
        Object1 current value:
        <xp:text escape="true" id="output" value="#{object1.value}" />
    </div>

    <xp:button value="Update" id="updateButton2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" />
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Java-class (ds.DataTest)

```
package ds;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class DataTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String value = "";

    public DataTest() { /* Constructor */ }

    public void sayHello(String text){
        System.out.println("Hello from: " + text);
    }

    public void update() {
        value = Double.toString( Math.random() );
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;       
    }

}
```

**What i like to do is**

```
<xp:view beforeRenderResponse="#{javascript:object1.update()}">
```

but that seems not possible, see what happens with the sayHello() calls.

First request
[image: Pageload]

Followup requests
[image: followup]

I appreciate every idea or hint :)

Comment: Did you consider using a sessionScope variable to store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important design principle for any custom control is encapsulation. If you drag it onto a canvas (page, customControl) it should work without any dependency on existing conditions.

So parameters a control uses should be, well parameters. Define them as custom parameters in your control definition.

Then you have 2 options: use a SsJS object you keep in the viewScope or use a managed bean in the viewScope.

Let's say your controls need a parameter called color, then the control would be called like this:

```
  <xc:myControl color="#{pageBean.color}"></xc:myControl>
```

In your bean you could do all the computations in the constructor which is called exactly once per page (that's what you want isn't it?) or lazy loaded when needed:

```
    public synchronized String getColor() {
            if(this.color==null) {
                  this.initColor();
            }
            return this.color;
    }
```

Lazy loading only makes sense if the values don't interdepend.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: My thought - use request scope instead (with lazy loading as you mentioned). That ensures recalculation on every request, but just once per request.

Comment: Thank you very much, a managed-bean on requestScope sounds great.
But it seems that a managed-bean are shared between all custom-controls, an i like to instantiate one per custom-control.
How would i achive the instantiation, when i would like to use the requestScope with a POJO? 

<???   ???="#{javascript: requestScope.put( ??? , new MyJavaClass())}" />

Comment: You could use the Facet pattern and have ONE bean that returns you objects for the various controls if they need different things. You would want to implement the Map interface

Comment: I understand - and i guess i can use the getCCId() from Sven Hasselbach (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413884/get-the-id-of-a-custom-control) to identify the current custom-control. Thanks a lot, you guys are awesome :)