# XPages: losing variables in partially refreshed custom controls

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans

I could do with some help once again...

We built our own forms in XPages. Forms are defined by a user in Notes, and they are used through XPages/web. We added several managed beans to get more grip on the data used by the page and controls that are on it. The whole thing is heavily nested, the form control can be used more than once on a page, repeat controls are used as well, and now I need to partially refresh a panel.

Some of the code:

```
<xp:panel id="ccAnyForm">
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="formulaire">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.formName || compositeData.dataSource.getItemValueString("Formulaire")}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
        <xp:dataContext var="formdata">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:PageData.getForm(formulaire, compositeData.dataSource)}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:panel id="aFormulaire${javascript:compositeData.name}">
        <xe:switchFacet id="switchFacet1">
            <xe:this.selectedFacet><![CDATA[#{javascript:formdata.isTabbed()? "tabbed": "flat"}]]></xe:this.selectedFacet>
```

PageData is a Java bean, and I lose *formdata* when doing a partial refresh. If I *set partial execution mode* in the EventHandler (data validation is disabled), I get the error that says **formdata not found** on the last line of the snippet. If I clear *partial execution mode*, I get nothing at all: no error, no Java error, no SSJS error, nothing.

It must be my lack of understanding the life-cycle of objects and variables, for I prbably have to use ValueBindings or so, but I don't know how.

Help...

Comment: Just a little (not answer-related) advice: It's better not to use DYNAMICALLY bound dataContexts because they are frequently recalculated, even when using partial execution mode. For more information, check out this post by Sven Hasselbach: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1112

Comment: Seen that, thanks. I don't care much too for the recalculations, for the time being, because I cache the result of the first call in my code and return the same value each subsequent call. What makes this more difficult (to understand) for me is that the content can change every partial refresh.

Comment: Where are you caching the result of the first call? The dataContext is a dynamic binding so recalculates during each partial refresh. The partial refresh itself comprises a number of phases, so properties (like getValue() of a component) may change in different phases.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen dataContexts recalculate as null, particularly when dependent on other dataContexts. I think in Apply Request Values phase. When I had that I changed the code to only calculate in Render Response phase.

However, I don't think that work for you, because the Switch control will need the value before Render Response, and there's no easy way to get hold of which other phase is running.

The approach I'd take is to have a property in your bean (e.g. `showTabbed`) that holds which Switch facet to show. Call a bean method to set that property on page load. Then in your partial refresh, call the method again, checking whether the Formulaire field has changed to determine whether or not to call `setShowTabbed(boolean)` again. That will minimise the number of calls even more and should prevent the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried without a DataContext, using 'local' variables, but then I sometimes get data from other incarnations of the same custom control. I therefore think that I should be using some type of ValueBinding: set the binding during load time and reuse it during other phases. There could be a different way, though. If I could find some way to define a unique id for the current custom control, I'd store everything in viewScope variables (or in a bean). I couldn't find such an id (I think I tested what this.getId() returns after a partial refresh, but I'm not sure...).

Comment: A nice and easy way of setting and using the custom control's id has been posted by @KnutHerrmann as an answer to the following stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413884/get-the-id-of-a-custom-control

Comment: Do you have the same custom control multiple times on the same XPage? Or is the bean scoped to a higher level than viewScope? If you only have the custom control once on that XPage and the bean is only viewScoped, then you should not get data from other incarnations on the custom control.

Comment: As ever, Tim Tripcony answered the problem some time ago. dataContexts in panels get cleaned up during Invoke Application, which is why the variables are null during the partial refresh http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9CD3JN

Comment: If you need the same Java object multiple times on a page, try using dataObject instead of a bean. dataObject will allow you to create an instance of the Class and scope it to a particular Panel rather than to viewScope. That will allow you to use a property on the class even if the custom control exists multiple times on the XPage.